# EF4 Code First create new table

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Is there a way when i add a new entity to my Code First configuration the table gets automatically added so i don't have to worry about updating my DB with new tables?

Answer (score 2):

you can add

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContext>());
```

in you r application start . It will recreate database for you if you have modified your configuration.
And if you do not want to drop and create database (To incremental development) you can use `SqlMigrations`. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx

Comment: Is there anything I can do, to avoid loosing my already added data?

Comment: @jonny_d you can use EF migrations

Answer (score 0):

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

> Setting an Initialization Strategy
>
> In the next section we are going to start changing our model which in turn means the database schema needs to change as well. Currently there is no ‘out of the box’ solution to evolve your existing schema in place. Database evolution is something we are currently working on and a sample of the direction we are heading is provided in a recent design blog post.
>
> There is however the opportunity to run some custom logic to initialize the database the first time a context is used in an AppDomain. This is handy if you want to insert seed data for test runs but it’s also useful to re-create the database if the model has changed. In CTP5 we include a couple of strategies you can plug in but you can also write custom ones.
>
> Add a using statement for System.Data.Entity.Database at the top of Program.cs
>
> ```
> using System.Data.Entity.Database;
> ```
>
> For the walkthrough we just want to drop and re-create the database whenever the model has changed, so at the top of the Main method in my Program class I’ve added the following code
>
> ```
> DbDatabase.SetInitializer<ProductContext>(
>     new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>());
> ```