# Error of Database.Table Objet is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I've created 2 models (User & Poste) with their controllers (UserController & PosteController) thanks to the method of creation with 'Read/Write actions and views, using Entity Framework'.

When i would like to access to the view of User or Poste, that's mean when I put /Poste (or /User) in my URL to access to the index, this error appears to me :

> Object Name 'dbo.Poste' invalid. or Object Name 'dbo.User' invalid.

This is the model of User :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Matricule :")]
        public string Matricule { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom :")]
        public string Nom_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Le {0} doit avoir au minimum {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Mot de passe :")]
        public string passWord { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Type :")]
        public string Type_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ID_UF :")]
        public string ID_UF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the Controller of User :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication2.Models;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{ 
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /User/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /User/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /User/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /User/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {            
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

and this the context Class (GammeContext) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class GammeContext:DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }

         public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I added in my web.config file :

```
<add name="GammeContext" connectionString="Data Source=SWEET-DE396641E\SQLEXPRESS;database=Flux; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check database whether User table exist or not by writing this query in new query editor window:

```
select * from dbo.User
```

may be you are able to run this:

```
select * from User
```

it is because this table schema is attached with your default user rather than 'dbo' object.

To fixed this you need to copy User to dbo.User by running following query:

```
select * into dbo.User from User
```

Comment: no, the table 'User' didn't exist, i want that be created automatically by the code.
Infact, I have already created the table 'Poste' and insert a value in its . But when i add a new model 'User' and i try to did the same thing as Poste (create the table and insert), this error appears

Comment: Are you using EF? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047900/ef4-code-first-create-new-table

Comment: yes i am using EF,,,i saw ur link,, sorry but i don't find where i will put this : Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContext>());
Application start ?? where ??

Comment: See this tutorial and you can also download their code to see the method of Code first EF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Comment: Thx Muhammad for the Tuto but it doesn't much with my application.
Infact, in the tuto, he use one file for all the models,,,,although i use file for each model

Comment: I add this to my ContextClass :
public GammeContext()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(
         new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GammeContext>());

        }
this error appers now :
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.